# Get current price from active date

Tags: sql-server

I need to find the active price for item from a price history table. I'm really battling with the logic and would appreciate some help. I've tried some of the solutions on this site but could not find a query that works for me.

Here's an example:

Table A is my master item table.
Table B is my price history table, this table contains past, current and future prices.

I need to join table B to table A on the item number and select the current active price.

**Table A**

| Item |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 456 |

**Table B**

| Item | Price | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 50 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-11-30 |
| 123 | 100 | 2021-12-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| 123 | 200 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 456 | 75 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-10-30 |
| 456 | 125 | 2021-11-01 | 2022-03-20 |
| 456 | 250 | 2022-03-21 | 2022-12-31 |

So my requests should look like the below

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 100 |
| 456 | 125 |

Comment: It typically pays to have an IsCurrent or null EndDate on the price history table to easily identify the current price.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the current date to the start and end range:

```sql
SELECT a.Item, b.Price
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON b.Item = a.Item
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN b.StartDate AND b.EndDate;
```

Comment: GETDATE returns a datetime and the date columns will be "up" converted for comparison. When GETDATE returns a value for the last date of a period, the comparison will not evaluate correctly.

Comment: @SMor Then use `CAST(GETDATE() AS date)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Table B only:

```
select item, 
price
from "Table B"
where getdate() between "Start Date" and "End Date"
```

This assumes you don't need items in Table A that don't appear in Table B, and that there are no overlapping date ranges.

Comment: Same problem as I mentioned in the other answer.